# Is hyperdex still being maintained?

Tags: hyperdex

I stumbled across hyperdex.org, a nosql database contender, after reading on hackingdistributed.com/tag/hyperdex/

Having read their documentation and browsed their git repository, it looks like a relatively promising piece of technology (I most like the easy cluster deploy and backup).

However, all trails (except a handful of edits in the macaroon lib) seem to go dead as of Oct2015.  Has the project been abandoned?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We have nothing to do with that project, and have no idea what its status/road map is.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the main developer of HyperDex.  Per https://github.com/rescrv/HyperDex/issues/232 I posted:

"I've shifted my focus to developing Consus and am no longer a part of the company or research group behind HyperDex."

Comment: look likes a dying project